# Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, next.js

I'm trying to develop an app with React and Node based on this [documentation](https://developers.shopify.com/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react):

I followed the tutorial step by step but I'm stuck in testing the app with this URL format:

I replaced the ngrok address and my shopify store but I get the 404 error (This page could not be found.)

I found the same question in this [link](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Oauth-error-invalid-request-with-React-and-Node/td-p/476014). So I renamed the .env to process.env but I still have the same problem.

Here is the **.env file**:

[image]

**package.json :**

[image]

**server.js :**

[image]

**The error :**

[image]

Comment: You likely have a typo or something on your whitelist. Check out this github issue - https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/486

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is an issue with your callback URL you have to define your app URL and callback URL in your shopify partner account where you create shopify app

[Shopify partner account](https://partners.shopify.com)

You have to do as follow

open apps >> yourapp >> app setup >> Insert In URLs(Whitelisted redirection URL(s))

Once you whitelist your URL there then the issue is solve

Comment: I was doing the same thing, I just forgot to add the "s" to http for the app URL.
Now it's working

Comment: yes shopify accept only https end points that's why define as https

Comment: This hack works for me : https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/486#issuecomment-433280268

Answer (score 32):

I don't think my answer is going to help many , But i am going to put it here anyway. So i had the same issue recently and i tried everything in stack-overflow and shopify community. And finally the problem was ***i had mistakenly copied my another app's apikey***. So even if the apiKey is wrong the error probably you are going to face is the same "The redirect uri is not whitelisted."

Comment: ugh did this too! creating a staging/test app vs. the production. utilizing wrong api keys!!

Comment: I had this same issue, and kept trying and trying, API Key mismatch from .env was the problem for me not redirect url.

Answer (score 13):

Mistake I was doing that I forgot to postpend `/auth/callback` to Forwarding URL to the **Allowed redirection URL(s)** section generated by following command:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

so redirect url will be like:

```
https://SOME_STRING.ngrok.io/auth/callback
```

Comment: This comment saves me, some old instruction gives outdated call back url(or wrong) like https://SOME_STRING.ngrok.io/shoptify/callback

Answer (score 4):

Your Whitelisted redirection URL must be `https`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that **App URL** and **Redirection URL** in App Setup is correct
something like -

1. App URL => https://example.com/
2. Redirection URL => https://example.com/auth/callback (make sure don't put "/" in the last)

and in your project HOST should be: https://example.com/

this will surely help you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had a `'/'` at the end of SHOPIFY_APP_URL in the .env file, so the redirect url was wrong with `'//auth/callback'`

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally used the `http` address instead of the `https` one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that will happen once you restart your ngrok, and your ngrok address url has changed, you have to manually update your new ngrok in the following part:

- Your AppUrl and Redirection Url in App setup. (Shopify dashboard)
- In your .env file, Where you defined your SHOPIFY_APP_URL. (Code Editor)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was that the SHOPIFY_API_KEY and SHOPIFY_API_SECRET in the .env file were in quotes which are the same in your case too. For this quote error also, it was showing the same error. Basically it is the wrong API keys error. Can you try removing quotes and try again?

If that doesn't work, please check you are using HTTPS URL and not HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in this error for 5-6 hours and it was just because I used ngrok and the https in ngrok is not working very well...
so I upload all of my content to a real server with https subdomain and everything is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check these for the host variable in your env file:

1. There should be no trailing `/` on the URL.
2. there should be no protocol mentioned for the URL

`HOST=abcxyz.com` and not `HOST:https://abcxyz.com/`

Answer (score 0):

## [ Solved ] 2022-08-03

I ran into the same error when I was trying to install Shopify App on Shopify Development Store for testing.

> Make sure that there are no trailing slashes when copying and pasting the `ngrok` url in `.env` file

I was getting this error because I used a trailing slash - `https://<Your ngrok url>/`
. Using it without trailing slash `https://<Your ngrok url>` fixed the issue.

Also, make sure that you include the trailing slash in your App Settings in Shopify Admin. Even if you don't include it, Shopify will save it with a trailing slash automatically.

Next, test installing your app. If you see any other error then make sure that you are using proper Shopify API scopes in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was that, in my `beginAuth` method, I had the whole url as the callback. It just wants the path.

I took it from

```
let authRoute = await Shopify.Auth.beginAuth(
    req,
    res,
    process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE,
    'https://stuff.ngrok.io/auth/shopify/callback',
    false
 )
```

to

```
let authRoute = await Shopify.Auth.beginAuth(
    req,
    res,
    process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE,
    '/auth/shopify/callback',
    false
)
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it was because I accidentally commented out the code where I set *accessToken* and *shop*

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when you use HTTP instead of HTTPS in allow redirection links secession in Shopify.