# Shopify app Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted with firebase

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, shopify-app

I need to host a Nextjs Shopify app on Firebase, when I use Heroku it works, but with Firebase hosting and firebase functions I get a webpage with `Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted`. I have added the whitelist URI correctly.

This is the URI looks like when I get the error:

```
https://test-store-advoz.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?state=160197157618000&scope=read_products&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-advoz-342ea.cloudfunctions.net%2Fauth%2Fcallback&grant_options%5B%5D=per-user
```

Comment: Check this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931719/12857703), it might have something to do with what is said there.